# Error cobertura in sonar "Too small initial heap"

Tags: maven, sonarqube, cobertura

I'm using sonar and cobertura (for code coverage). I'm baffled with the problem I'm facing. If I run

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

I saw the following error during executions

```
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default-cli) @ hss-core <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default-cli) @ hss-core ---
[INFO] Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap

[ERROR] Error in Cobertura Report generation: Unable to generate Cobertura Report for project.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to generate Cobertura Report for project.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:93)
```

if I run the cobertura plugin directly using the following

```
mvn cobertura:cobertura
```

There is no error as above, and display the following output, which I assume was the expected output.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default-cli) @ hss-core <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default-cli) @ hss-core ---
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 39 classes.
Report time: 1035ms
```

I have set the MAVEN_OPTS (MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m) environment variable, but still getting the error.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

It almost feel that you omitted 'm' in your -Xms parameter:

```
$java -Xms512 -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap
```

Won't hurt to check values for other environment variables to see if there is anything Java-related defined ('set' command on Windows should print them all) - check _JAVA_OPTS, MAVEN_OPTS etc.

Comment: Done that, thanks though. Besides, if it did exists, it doesn't make any sense why "mvn cobertura:cobertura" runs OK, but "mvn sonar:sonar" does not.

Comment: When I first read this answer I thought it was insinuating the missing m was after the X: '-Xs512', but for me the missing m was for megs after the 512.  I had -Xms512 when it should have been -Xms512m.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar Cobertura Plugin had a specific parameter to increase the memory allocated to the Cobertura process: sonar.cobertura.maxmem

For instance, you can run: mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.cobertura.maxmem=512m

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+coverage+plugins#Cobertura

Comment: The problem seems to be `Too small initial heap` which is to do with minimum heap size.

Comment: I have tried using the <configuration><maxmem>..</maxmem><configuration>, this is the same thing, right? Still producing the same error. :(